# Problem of attaching a database to visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I press add connection in database explorer then put the server name which is Rabbitmasterpc

windows Authentication, attach a database file:  --> I browse to the database i attached.. give it a logical name..click 'ok'. And what I get:

> "A network-related or instance specific error occured while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessable. Verify that the instance name is correct  and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow removte connections. (provider:
>   Named Pipes Provider, error:40- Could not open a connection to SQL
>   server)"

UPDATE:

```
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1673
```

The article says it is in facets..but i dont have it inside

Answer (score 0):

Check if SQL Server is configured (via SQL Server Configuration Manager) to accept *remote* connections.

Also, you may need to check the Connections property page for your database in Management Studio, as well as firewall settings:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: hmm...how do i do that. I have the database attached to sql server 2008.. it doesnt appear in sql server section in visual studio 2010. :(

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd do you have access to the machine on which the SQL Server is installed?

Comment: Configure Surface Area Configuration for SQL Server 2008--- I am trying to find this in sql server 2008

Comment: it should be under Microsoft SQL Server xxx / Configuration Tools in the start menu

Comment: it should be in facets.. in 2008 it should be in facets section..but it isnt theree...

Comment: I think i got inside it is in server configuration..AdhocRemoteQueriesEnabled=----> change to true..or are there more properties that i need to change

Comment: alright, I just realized it is replaced with another name on SQL 2008: SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: @prusswan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1756/discussion-between-dmitry-makovetskiyd-and-prusswan)

Answer (score 0):

Try using code below to open the connection.

```
Try
        Dim objconnection As SqlConnection = New  _
            SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=DATABASENAME;" & _
                          "user ID = YOURUSERID; password = YOURPASSWORD;")

        objconnection.Open()
        objconnection.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("Database Connection Success")
Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Database Connection Error: " & ex.Message)
End Try
```